# magento2 Checkout Page Shipping address

Tags: magento2

i am working on magento2 checkout page and i want to add tool tip after street address in shipping information section how can i do this please adivce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following way using plugin:

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
        <plugin name="sr_ModuleName_checkout_layout_processor"
                type="SR\MagentoCommunity\Plugin\Block\LayoutProcessor" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/Plugin/Block/LayoutProcessor.php

```
<?php
namespace SR\MagentoCommunity\Plugin\Block;

class LayoutProcessor
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject
     * @param array $jsLayout
     * @return array
     */
    public function afterProcess(
        \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
        array $jsLayout
    ) {
        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']
        ['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['street']['children'][0]['config']['tooltip'] = [
            'description' => 'This is test tooltip for street'
        ];

        return $jsLayout;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not working. I added your files, ran setup and static commands but not helpful.

Comment: Did you create new module using SR\MagentoCommunity?

Comment: yes I created a new module, but not added etc module.xml, should I add that also?

Comment: yes, please. Add module.xml and registration.php

Comment: just give me 10 mins, I'll add that and let you know

Comment: Thanks alot, it worked! really appreciated.